# XMPP with Java Asmack library and X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM

Tags: java, android, facebook, xmpp, asmack

I've intentionally copy-pasted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317329/xmpp-with-java-asmack-library-supporting-x-facebook-platform) dont be angry for duplicate.
There are several unclear moments for me in the topic:

1)

```
xmpp.login(apiKey + "|" + sessionKey, sessionSecret, "Application");
```

> sessionKey is the second part of the access token. If the token is in
>   this form, AAA|BBB|CCC, the BBB is the session key

But my access token looks like: BAADcfjCWMLABAIyzRSZA69eAtA9Dr3EQVlXA8Ql6rr5odDWxNYZCHhssiaar8S0gaPLZAm1ZBKCqWO3QFegJPR39hT0JR5ZCyIP1AJZC19qh9mFAExUd9KDjJ05yjE3IUZD

so I cant see any "second part"...

2)

> sessionSecret is obtained using the old REST API with the method
>   auth.promoteSession. To use it, it's needed to make a Http get to this
>   url:
>
> https://api.facebook.com/method/auth.promoteSession?access_token=yourAccessToken
>
> Despite of the Facebook Chat documentation says that it's needed to
>   use your application secret key, only when I used the key that
>   returned that REST method I was able to make it works. To make that
>   method works, you have to disable the Disable Deprecated Auth Methods
>   option in the Advance tab in your application settings.

I've read [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.promoteSession/) that REST is deprecated and

> We will not be supporting this method in the Graph API.

What should I do? I'm using only Graph API. Is there any other way to get sessionSecret?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this one and it worked for me .

First of all Edit your SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism class . Copy and paste this code .

```
package com.facebook.android;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.Sasl;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

import android.util.Log;


public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

    private static final String NAME              = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";

    private String              apiKey            = "";
    private String              accessToken        = "";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(NAME, ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String apiKey, String host, String accessToken) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        if (apiKey == null || accessToken == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
        }

        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.hostname = host;

        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, cbh);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
        byte[] response = null;

        if (challenge != null) {
            String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
            Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

            String version = "1.0";
            String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
            String method = parameters.get("method");

            String composedResponse =
                "method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8") +
                        "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8") +
                        "&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "utf-8") +
                        "&api_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8") +
                        "&call_id=0" +
                        "&v=" + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8");
            response = composedResponse.getBytes();
        }

        String authenticationText = "";

        if (response != null) {
            authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response);
        }

        // Send the authentication to the server
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
    }

    private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] params = query.split("\\&");

        for (String param : params) {
            String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
            map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Then use this method in your activity class from where you want to login to facebook.

```
private void testLogin(){
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
        xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAppId());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Connected to " + xmpp.getHost());

        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Unable to " + xmpp.getHost());

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            xmpp.login(PreferenceConnector.APP_ID, mFacebook.getAccessToken());

            getRoster(xmpp);


        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Hi @JanshairKhan I am trying to you above mentioned method login on facebook in android using asmack library , it giving me exception as "SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM:" , any suggestion ?

Comment: still getting "SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM:" ,