# Facebook Chat application using XMPP , Spark or SparkWeb java

Tags: java, facebook, oauth-2.0, xmpp

i am trying to make a facebook chat application for my website using facebook XMPP, Spark or SparkWeb and java. im not know how to start work for it. i am make application for facebook in php and dont know how to authenticate users to my app. please help me for this topic. give me reference or link so i can make this app.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ignite Realtime(developer of Spark) provides an library called SmackAPI. You can use it to implement your own client and integrate it into your website.

[SmackAPI](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp)

To use the Facebook XMPP chat you need to know some information:

```
Host:chat.facebook.com
Port:5222
Username: myfacebookuser@chat.facebook.com
Password: myfacebookpassword
```

Comment: Facebook does not allow XMPP authentication with username and password anymore. You can only authenticate over OAuth 2.0 for XMPP with their X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL mechanism.
see: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/09/09/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: Alex, and what's an OAuth 2.0 XMPP client?

Comment: @Nemo You need to implement your own Facebook authentication mechanisum, please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend [Smack](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack)'s `SASLMechanism` to implement the Facebook authentication mechanism. BTW, Spark (you mentioned) is an XMPP client, which uses Smack library.

- An example implementation and related discussions on the Smack Dev forum:
  https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/47216
- Several implementations you can find on stackoverflow:

  - [How to create XMPP chat client for facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045241/how-to-create-xmpp-chat-client-for-facebook?rq=1)
  - [XMPP with Java Asmack library supporting X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317329/xmpp-with-java-asmack-library-supporting-x-facebook-platform/5843759#5843759)