# I want to register a custom SASL mechanism with the XMPP Connection instead of the default one

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, asmack, smack-stack

I have been struggling with this for long . I want to do something similar to what is mentioned in 
[XMPP with Java Asmack library supporting X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317329/xmpp-with-java-asmack-library-supporting-x-facebook-platform)

I am going to prepare my custom SASL mechanism and similarly, on the XMPP server side, we are going to register for that mechanism so that we can authenticate the user using our designed protocol rather than the default authentication of smack client and XMPP server.

Do I want to know how can I register that custom SASL mechanism using my smack client?

I can't find anything online, all I can see is previous snippets of code using old methods like:

```
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism(SASLAuthentication)
```

These mnethods like SUpportSASLMechanism don't even exist anymore in the smack libraries.
Can anyone please suggest something.